# Letter swapping method. Double Check please

Tags: java

So I finished this method (supposed to have a String as parameter) that was supposed to switch each pair of adjacent letters. If it was an even number of letters it would do as it should. However if it was an odd amount of letters it would leave the last letter alone. For example, **example** would become **xemalpe**, and **hello there** would be **ehll ohtree**. The problem here is that if it is an odd number phrase it would delete the last letter. Example being **the** would turn out as **ht**. Can someone double check what I did wrong with it? The code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    swapPairs("hello the");
}

public static void swapPairs(String S){
    int cl = S.length() - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < cl; i= i + 2) {
        System.out.print(S.charAt(i + 1));
        System.out.print(S.charAt(i));
        if (i == cl -1 ) {
            System.out.print(S.charAt(cl));
        } else {
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

I sort of debated whether or not I should have the homework tag there seeing as I already finished it but decided to leave it there just because it was.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check S.length() % 2 (that's the mod operator), if it's 0, that's an even length string, 1, odd.  Then you can treat it differently depending on which case you have.

Answer (score 0):

When the input string is of even length (say example word 'then' of  length 4 )
your code

```
int cl = S.length() - 1;      
    for(int i = 0; i < cl;
```

correctly makes the last pass of the for loop occur with i pointing to the next to last character (eg i=2 , the 3rd character 'e')

Note: the 'if' code is not relevant for this case.

But for an odd length (say example word 'hello' length 5)
the last pass of the for loop also occurs with i=2
- the next increment to i=4 fails i

AND your 'if' code WITHIN the for loop never gets the chance to be executed!